# remove charset from Content-type in express response

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, content-type

Im working on the following api call using express library:

```
router.get('/WebServers', (req, res) => {
  log.debug('api v2 - List WebServers');
  const servers = webServersModel.transformWebServers();
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({WebServers: servers});
});
```

My client for some unkown reason accepts only http headers with content type:"application/json"
however express seems to append "; charset=utf-8" to all of my resonses.
after digging around Ive found this piece of code in the express/lib/response.js file: 
[image]

Express seems to be hard-coding the appending of the charset to the response.
following this code Ive tried adding to the top of my code the following line: `express.static.mime.charsets.lookup=function() {};`
however that didnt work. any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Replace res.set() with res.writeHead().  Fixed it for me last week :)