How to prevent NestJS from modifying response headers?
    res.setHeader("Content-type", "image/webp");

    console.log(res.getHeaders()); // Content-type: image/webp
   
    res.send(result.data);        // receive Content-type: image/webp; charset=utf-8

setHeader docs:
Sets a single header value. If the header already exists in the to-be-sent headers, its value will be replaced. Use an array of strings to send multiple headers with the same name.
Why I am getting this 'charset-utf-8' applied somewhere after using res.send?
How can I prevent this, since there are some other headers I would want to override, for example 'x-powered-by': 'ImageX', but Nest.js changes it's value to 'Express'. How can I prevent this behaviour?
I tried accessing const rawResponse = res.socket; but it didn't help since before executing res.send it has the correct values anyway.

this is not nestjs, this is Expressjs changing stuff. So you must search on how to avoid that in Express

thank you Micael, I've been able to find a solution quickly after this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311432/remove-charset-from-content-type-in-express-response

remove charset from Content-type in express response
Use res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": contentType, ...otherHeaders }).end(result.data);
